# What is the meaning and the usage of " save" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

I don't understand the last sentence of the following paragraph, especially the meaning and usage of "save us with that".

> 3:28
>   So we come to one person, and we basically are asking them to give us what once an entire village used to provide. Give me belonging, give me identity, give me continuity, but give me transcendence and mystery and awe all in one. Give me comfort, give me edge. Give me novelty, give me familiarity. Give me predictability, give me surprise. And we think it's a given, and toys and lingerie are going to **save** us with that.

Source:[Esther Perel: The secret to desire in a long-term relationship](https://www.ted.com/talks/esther_perel_the_secret_to_desire_in_a_long_term_relationship/transcript?language=en#t-221440)

Comment: Perhaps 'to save us with that' means 'to help us make sure of that' or 'to do that for us'.

Comment: It's not a very well written text - hardly surprising, since it seems to be just a transcript of a *talk*.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for the meaning of poorly written text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esther Perel is fluent in English, and if you listen to her talk, you'll find her eloquent, but she makes a few non-idiomatic slips. In the paragraph above, she contrasts comfort with edge when she means edginess. Later on in the talk, in a passage you don't quote, she says "contract the gap", where "narrow the gap" would be more common.

In the passage you do quote, Ms Perel gives a list of contradictory qualities that she claims we have come to expect ("a given") in long-term relationships. Her thesis is that the contradictions drain the erotic energy from these relationships and that we think that

> toys [i.e., sex toys] and lingerie are going to save us with that.

She's using *with* in the sense of concerning, which would be fine in a sentence like

> toys and lingerie are going to involve us with that.

*That* must refer to the list of contradictions. It can't refer to toys and lingerie because that would take a **reflective pronoun**:

> toys and lingerie are going to involve us by **themselves**

But the verb *to save* licenses the preposition *from* to indicate the dangers avoided, so we'd expect

> toys and lingerie are going to save us **from** [all] that.

The preposition *with* combined with *to save* has the meaning of agency, so we say

> the victim of the crash could have been saved **with** a seatbelt.

(Synonymous with the substitution of the preposition *by*) But the toys and lingerie *are* the agents of salvation, so using *with* leaves the uncomfortable sense that they are the antecedent to *that* in the phrase *with that*. Of course, the context makes it clear that this cannot be what Ms Perel means.

Answer (score 1):

It means "prevent us from experiencing the predictably bad outcomes that tend to result from putting those kinds of expectations on one single relationship and person."   It is part of the more general use of the "prevent bad outcomes" meaning of "save."  The implication is that no individual human is likely to be able to meet those high expectations and be able to provide all that, not even with the help of those physical items.

The speaker's use of "we think" indicates the author's doubt about the claim that these physical items can really prevent those bad outcomes, supporting the point that they cannot.